# Can not understand this line of a popular deep Q learning program

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

https://github.com/yenchenlin/DeepLearningFlappyBird/blob/master/deep_q_network.py#L82

I have spend a lot of time to understand it.

Why use `tf.multiply`?

I can not find the math that support this multiply operation.

Comment: I think this question is better suited for https://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Every action has a Q_value.**

And the action input `a` is one-hot.

So this line is to choose the 'hot' Q_value.